# How to check if a double is null?

Tags: java, database, null, double

I'm querying a database and some of the results I'm getting are null. I'm setting these values to a variable with a datatype of double. Let's call the variable "results". So I tried setting up an if statement to see it equals Null which of course didn't work. Here is the code I have for that if statement:

```
if (results == null)
{
     results = 0;
}
```

The error I get with this code is:

```
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null
```

Is there a better way to determine if it's null?

Comment: You need to retrieve the value as something that can actually be `null`, like `Double`. Primitives can't be null.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Double` not a **double** as your type then you check against null.

Comment: Warning - simply declaring `results` to be `Double` instead of `double` won't fix the problem.  `Double results = rs.getDouble();` will **never** assign a `null` to `results`.

Comment: I find this answer to be useful for the general case of keeping track of whether a double value has been initialized or not.

Comment: But that wasn't the question that was asked.  And in the scenario that the OP asks about, this solution simply won't work.

Answer (score 58):

Firstly, a Java `double` cannot be a Java `null`, and cannot be compared with `null`.  (The `double` type is a primitive (non-reference) type and primitive types cannot be `null`.)  I'm therefore assuming the following:

- The "null" you are trying to detect is a NULL stored in the database that you are querying.
- You are using JDBC to query the database.

If you call [`ResultSet.getDouble(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble%28int%29), that returns a `double` not a `Double`, the documented behavior is that a NULL (from the database) will be returned as zero.  (See javadoc linked above.)  That is no help if zero is a legitimate value for that column.

Changing the declared type of `result` to `Double` instead of `double` as suggested by [Toby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090441/139985) **will not help**.  When the database contains NULL, the value assigned to `result` will be a `Double(0.0)`, not a `null`.

Here are two options that will work:

- Use [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) to test for a (database) NULL ... immediately after the `getDouble(...)` call.
- Use [`ResultSet.getObject(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(java.lang.String)), and test for `null` using `==`.

The `getObject` method will deliver a (non-NULL) value as a `Double` (assuming that the column type is `double`).  It is documented to return `null` for a NULL.  (For more information, [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) documents the default mappings of SQL types to Java types, and therefore what actual type you should expect `getObject` to deliver.)

Answer (score 8):

A double primitive in Java can never be null. It will be initialized to 0.0 if no value has been given for it (except when declaring a local double variable and not assigning a value, but this will produce a compile-time error).

More info on default primitive values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: They will only be initialized to 0.0 if they are instance variables.  Otherwise they have no value, not even null.

Comment: According to the docs, this only happens with local variables, and doing so will produce a compile-time error. If you can't compile the code, it is never executing, so a double can never be null or have no value in execution. I've updated my post anyways.

Comment: *"Otherwise they have no value, not even null."* - Strictly speaking, they have no value that is specified by the JLS, or that you can observe using Java code.  However, if you jump through enough hoops (and break abstraction boundaries that a sane programmer wouldn't dream of breaking) there will be a way to observe the bit pattern than an uninitialized local variable contains.  (Hint: native code).  And you could argue that that bit pattern is a value.

Answer (score 6):

To say that something "is null" means that it is a reference to the null value.  Primitives (int, double, float, etc) are by definition not reference types, so they cannot have null values.  You will need to find out what your database wrapper will do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

How are you getting the value of "results"? Are you getting it via ResultSet.getDouble()? In that case, you can check [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29).

Answer (score -1):

I believe Double.NaN might be able to cover this. That is the only 'null' value double contains.

Comment: It is not relevant to this scenario.